# Branches/Tags/Trunk in Version Control

Tags: svn, version-control

I have been studying svn for the last two days and would like to make sure I understand my stuff, and also have some questions about the scheme. Please correct me if I were wrong here:

Trunk: Main body of development. Contains every version: from the start until the present.

Branches: This file usually contains several subfolders such as bug fix branches or release branches. They contain files from a certain point in the trunk that is used for applying major changes to the code.

Tags: A point in time on the trunk or a branch that you wish to preserve. For example, version 2 is more stable than version 3, so one decides to save it in tags.

Questions:

1) Am I right with these three statements?

2) Branches and Tags seem very similar. Why don't we just have a separate branch that preserves Tags version?

3) When one checks out a project, he usually starts working on the trunk, branch or tags version?

4) Why would one prefer this framework? I personally think having three folders makes it more scattered. An example would be preferred. Thanks

Comment: Just a note - svn does not support branches/tags natively (only copies) - usual layout of directories in svn to emulate tags and branches is only a convention adopted by most svn users. There are projects out there, that don't follow "standard layout" of svn repo and place tags and branches all over the place. If you want to learn concept of tags and branches properly, then I strongly suggest learning proper version control system such as Git or Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

The main point you have to understand is that trunk/branches/tags is nothing but a suggested layout you are free to use or not. While it's a de-facto standard and it's strongly recommended there are situations where you can use a modified version or even not use it at all. It all comes from a design decision. Other version control tools provide built-in features for branching and tagging but Subversion doesn't. Instead, they preferred to let the user emulate these features with directories, taking benefit of the *cheap copies* concept.

In short: you are free to use branches and tags but, if you choose to, you have to use directories because there's no other way and sticking to the standard allows third-parties to understand automatically what you're doing (that includes both people like fellow developers and GUI tools like TortoiseSVN).

As about your question:

1. Some clarifications:

   - Main development is a popular choice but not the only possible one. It can also be the stable version or whatever you need it to be.
   - Trunk does not contain every version (the **repository** does). Trunk contains versions commited to trunk, just like any other directory.
2. Separate branch that preserves Tags version? And then how do you tell out branches (live) from tags (snapshot)?
3. You never work in a tag, tags are snapshots that shouldn't be altered. As about trunk/branch, it depends on what they contain.
4. I suspect your project is not versioned thus you don't find branches and tags useful. But sooner or later you'll want to start a feature that will take much time to complete and will break the codebase until it's done. Since Subversions is a centralised version control system you only have two options:

   1. Feature branches
   2. Do not use version control at all until you're done

### Example

```
trunk -> Work in progress for next version (2.0.2 or 2.1.0, to be decided)
branches
    legacy-1.0.x
    legacy-1.1.x
    legacy-1.2.x
    legacy-2.0.x
    new-memory-management
    storage-optimizations
tags
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.1.0
    1.2.0
    2.0.0-beta1
    2.0.0-beta2
    2.0.0
    2.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes
2. They are more than very similar. They're exactly the same thing. You put ttags under tags to make it clear that they're tags, and that you should thus not make modifications on these copies. You can also apply different rights of tags and branches to avoid tags to be written to. You can view a tag as a read-only branch.
3. It depends on the way you decided to work. Some people work exclusively in the trunk. Some other work exclusively in feature branches and keep the trunk stable. Several options are discussed in the free subversion book, IIRC.
4. Because it's conventional. Not that you're not forced to have everything checked out locally. You can simply have the trunk, or the branch you're currently working on, and switch from branch to branch, using a single working copy.

But the main question I would ask myself, if I were you, is: is it a good idea to learn SVN in the first place? Most people nowadays use Git or other DVCSes that make working with branches easier and faster.

I would learn git if I were you.